# listView drag and drop

Tags: android, gradle

Подскажите библиотеки listView drag and drop для gradle импорта в андроид студио, а то либо импортируются, но не компилятся либо студия не хочет переваривать eclipse проект, ну либо какие либо еще советы, а то ничего не получается совсем

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй эту либу, я думаю это лучший вариант из того, что есть в открытом доступе: https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView
Если не получается её импортировать, проверь есть ли в коде этой либы библиотеки из support, если есть, то тебе нужно исключить пакет androidx из своего проекта, если в том проекте нет библиотек из support, но есть androidx, то тебе придётся мигрировать твой проект на библиотеки из пакета androidx, заменив все пакеты support
В случае если с библиотеками всё норм, то советую просто подробнее изучить саму библиотеку или уже писать конкретные ошибки которые выскакивают

Comment: у меня там возникли проблемы с адаптером, никак не получается его поставить